# Highcharts bar graph doesn't show yaxis values

Tags: highcharts

I am facing a problem showing the y-axis values in a graph. This is my code :

```
var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'charts_container',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: selecte_company+' '+duration+' '+selecte_branch+' '+selected_menu 
            },
            colors: ['#ABD373', '#FFD285', '#EC5657'],
            legend: {
                itemStyle: {
                    color: '#737979'
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: xAxis
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: yAxis
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{}]
        };
        $.getJSON(dataLink, function(data) {
        console.log("data");
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.length);
        console.log(data[0].data.length);
            if (data[0].data.length == 0) {
                $('#charts_container').html('<p id="defalip";>No data found..</p>');
            } else {
                options.series = data;
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            }
        });
```

And my json is :

```
[{"name":"value1","data":[[0.91]]},{"name":"valur4 %","data":[[42.63]]}]
```

[image]

I want to show my data like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your data `[{"name":"value1","data":[[0.91]]},{"name":"valur4 %","data":[[42.63]]}]` you have the `name` set to `valueXXX` - this is what is going to be shown on the xAxis. If you want your chart to look like the rainfall example it would be best to look at the actual [code](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/) used to render it. You can see that there are multiple series:

```
series: [{
  name: 'Tokyo',
  data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

}, {
  name: 'New York',
  data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

}, {
  name: 'London',
  data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

}, {
  name: 'Berlin',
  data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]
}]
```

As well as a definition of what the xAxis categories are:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: [
    'Jan',
    'Feb',
    'Mar',
    'Apr',
    'May',
    'Jun',
    'Jul',
    'Aug',
    'Sep',
    'Oct',
    'Nov',
    'Dec'
  ],
  crosshair: true
},
```

In your code you have

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: xAxis
    },
```

I do not see where you are defining your `xAxis` list here.

To reproduce a graph like the demo you are going to need to produce multiple series and create an `xAxis.categories` array to hold what each point in each series will have as its xAxis label.

Comment: While all good points, I don't think this answers the question of why there are no labels on the y axis (which I don't know either. seems there is a data formatting issue that may be part of the problem though)

Comment: @jlbriggs Agreed. It seemed like the OP was on the wrong foot to begin with. Probably had something to do with their `categories: xAxis` code.

Comment: I don't think it's a data formatting problem, see: http://jsfiddle.net/8n7q2fyd/ But I assume, that somewhere OP uses `Highcharts.setOptions()`, which sets default values like formatters etc. Just the screenshot of the chart looks strange - translated all labels (xAxis.category and yAxis.title).